# Creating Complex view in Android Navigaton Drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-view

Hi I am working on an android application which uses slide menu. I am trying to create a remote like view in the slide menu. like one in the peel remote. How to create such a complex view in Navigation drawer?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        //your stuff goes here


    </FrameLayout>


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The FrameLayout with id navigation_drawer will be your drawer which you can load any complex view inside this using `Fragment`